# nginx Errno 32: Broken Pipe with certain requests

Tags: python, docker, nginx, wsgi, broken-pipe

I've got an NGINX/flask/Docker server using:
https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker
and it works for running small and infrequent requests. But if I try a number of large requests that involve downloading ~5mb worth of data from amazon s3 for each (lets say, 10 at once). I get this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 659, in inner
    srv.serve_forever()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 499, in serve_forever
    HTTPServer.serve_forever(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 233, in serve_forever
    self._handle_request_noblock()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 292, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.handle_error(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 290, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 318, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 331, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 652, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 216, in handle
    rv = BaseHTTPRequestHandler.handle(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 340, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 251, in handle_one_request
    return self.run_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 193, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 184, in execute
    write(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 165, in write
    self.wfile.write(data)
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I've tried adding more processes and threads to nginx/wsgi. My uwsgi.ini looks like so:

```
[uwsgi]
module = main
callable = application
processes = 8
threads = 2
```

and my nginx.conf looks like this:

```
server {
    location / {
        try_files $uri @app;
    }
    location @app {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /app/static;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: Anything in the nginx [`error_log`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log)? (perhaps at increased verbosity?)

Comment: Wait, your traceback shows that you’re using the built-in Python [`SocketServer`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/socketserver.html) (which is used by the Flask development server), not uWSGI. It looks like you’re launching your `.py` script directly, rather than through uWSGI. Something must be wrong about your configuration.